# Debugging a PHP to PostgreSQL Connection

Tags: php, postgresql, logging

What is the best way to see whats going on with a PHP connection to a PostgreSQL database from the log?

I've edited my "postgresql.conf" file to include debugging level 5 information (debug5) (maybe not needed??):

```
client_min_messages = debug5
log_min_messages = debug5
log_min_error_statement = debug5
```

however, the ./pg_log/postgresql-*.log file doesn't seem to include any helpful command or failed login information from PHP??

./pg_log/postgresql-*.log:

```
DEBUG:  pg_toast_2619: vac: 0 (threshold 52), anl: 0 (threshold 51)
DEBUG:  CommitTransaction
DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       STARTED; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0, nestlvl: 1, children: 
DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 8 callbacks to make
DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make
DEBUG:  exit(0)
DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
DEBUG:  server process (PID 20524) exited with exit code 0
```

PHP:

```
<?php                                                                                          
// Connecting, selecting database                                                              
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=orion user=USERNAME password=PASSWORD")   
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());                                           

// Performing SQL query                                                                        
$query = 'SELECT * FROM main';                                                                 
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());                         

// Printing results in HTML                                                                    
echo "<table>\n";                                                                              
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {                                   
    echo "\t<tr>\n";                                                                           
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {                                                            
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";                                                      
    }                                                                                          
    echo "\t</tr>\n";                                                                          
}                                                                                              
echo "</table>\n";                                                                             

// Free resultset                                                                              
pg_free_result($result);                                                                       

// Closing connection                                                                          
pg_close($dbconn);                                                                             
?>
```

Is there anyway to see whats going on with the PHP connection to PostgreSQL in detail?  The other log files in ./pg_clog/ look like "0000" and are binary?  I'm using the default values for everything else in the postgresql.conf file.

Comment: Check the database credentials by logging in on the command line

Comment: The log says `server process (PID 20524) exited with exit code 0`. I would assume that that means the server couldn't even start.

Comment: The server seems to be running because I can connect to it from phppgadmin and also python/psql does connect.

Comment: `pg_clog` and `pg_xlog` are *not log files* in the sense  you are thinking. It is *vital* that you not modify or delete them. They are *transaction logs*, part of the database's crash safety system, and deleting them can badly damage your database.

Comment: Also, `debug5` is way too much detail. Use `log_min_messages = 'LOG'` or at most `debug1` unless you're chasing a bug in the PostgreSQL server backend. `exit code 0` is *success*, a normal exit, and is exactly what I'd expect.

Comment: Also, debug5 seems to mostly have process information.  What I was looking for was a log file that includes the SQL Command Strings sent from PHP, Python, ... or PSQL.

Comment: /etc/httpd/logs/error_log is also helpful for other...